# Pass a information between content and PopUp on Chrome Extensions

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

i'm trying to pass some information from the content.js to the Popup.js on a chrome extension, but i dont know how to do it, i've already read the docs, but still dont get how it works, i only make the content.js work. my idea is to create a list on the popup whic is based on a array thats the content.js provides.

**The content.js:**

```
console.log("Working");
const list = new Array();
const interval = setInterval(() => {
let names = document.getElementsByClassName("cS7aqe");
console.log(names);

if(names.length > 0){

    for(let name of names){
        console.log(name.textContent);

        list.includes(name.textContent) ? null : list.push(name.textContent);

    }

    console.log(list);

    let options = {
        active: true,
        currentWindow: true
    }

    chrome.tabs.query(options, gotTabs);

}

},1000)

function gotTabs(tabs) {
   console.log("gotTabs executed");
   console.log(tabs); 
   let msg = {
       msg: list
   }
   chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tabs[0], msg);
}
```

**The popup.js:**

```
// for(let name of list){

//     chrome.browserAction.getPopup(() => {
//         let ul = document.getElementById("List");
//         let li = document.createElement("li");
//         li.innerHTML = name;
//         ul.appendChild(li);
//     })

//     }


chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);

function gotMessage(message, sender, sendResponse) {
    console.log(message);
}
```

**The popup.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Gerar Chamada</title>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Chamada</h1>
    <ul id="chamada"></ul>
</body>
</html>
```

**The manifest.json**

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "MeetsChamada",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": [
                "https://meet.google.com/*"
                ],
            "css": [
                "style.css"
            ],
            "js": [
                "content.js"
            ]
        }
    ],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_popup": "popup/popup.html"
    }
}
```

Comment: One significant issue you'll run into is that the popup.js is only active when the popup is shown. Otherwise the page does not exist and therefore cannot accept messages. My recommendation would be to have the content script pass a message to the background script to keep the array state. Then have the popup request that information with a message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problems:**

1. Content scripts can't use most of `chrome` API such as chrome.tabs or browserAction
2. Content scripts run when the web page has loaded
3. Popup runs only when it's shown
4. chrome.browserAction.getPopup returns the popup's file name, not its window object

**Solution:**

The content script should listen to messages, do stuff only upon receiving a message, send a response with data. The popup will send a message periodically using setInterval - it's safer because the web page can clear DOM timers of the content script by accident.

popup.html: move the script to the end of html so it runs when DOM is ready:

```html
  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</body>
```

popup.js:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, ([tab]) => {
  setInterval(ping, 1000, tab);
});

function ping(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, 'getData', data => {
    const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
    ul.textContent = '';
    ul.append(...res.map(createItem));
  });
}

function createItem(text) {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.textContent = text;
  return li;
}
```

content.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener((msg, sender, sendResponse) => {
  if (msg === 'getData') {
    const elems = [...document.getElementsByClassName('cS7aqe')];
    const texts = elems.map(el => el.textContent);
    const uniqTexts = [...new Set(texts)];
    sendResponse(uniqTexts);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you! your answer was very helpful!